Choose sample size in Linear mixed models. Ethical considerations
There are no reference articles on this topic, the linear mixed model requires real data on results to calculate the sample size, unlike an anova model that requires data on power, significance and effect size.
Could you base the sample size on studies that, although not the same, were similar, and calculate the power a posteriori? Or would it no longer be necessary, because it would be enough to report the results and the effect size?
What would be the most recommended option for choosing the sample size for a linear mixed model in this situation?

What does this have to do with the "ethical considerations" in your title??

I have the same question as whuber. We do have an "[tag:ethics]" tag with some questions related to ethics in statistics, but it's unclear how your question relates at all to that. Can you edit your question to clarify that, and add the tag if it's relevant? It would make your question much more visible to people exploring the existing list of questions related to ethics.

LMM requires more "guesswork" for estimating the sample size, to the point of requiring specific data on the group means as well as their relationship coefficients. Assuming this is the first study on the topic, to what extent can it be ethical to make conjectures about the required data? And then, once the study is completed, what happens if your initial guesses do not match the results obtained in the study? For this reason, could doing a retrospective analysis be considered a better option? That is, carry out a study with a specific sample, and report the power obtained.

You seem to use "ethical" to refer to accuracy or correctness or utility or something like that.  The questions you pose have no discernible ethical dimensions or ramifications.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Could you base the sample size on studies that, although not the same, were similar, and calculate the power a posteriori?"
You can definitely look at studies that are similar, even though not identical to your intended design, but you should use the effect sizes these studies found as a basis of your own a priori sample size calculations. You shouldn't do a posteriori power calculations.
Apart from that, there are actually quite a few simulation studies providing some guidelines for choosing sample size in linear mixed models, e.g.
Arend, M. G., & Schäfer, T. (2019). Statistical power in two-level models: A tutorial based on Monte Carlo simulation. Psychological methods, 24(1), 1-19. https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/met0000195
Kumle, L., Võ, M.LH. & Draschkow, D. Estimating power in (generalized) linear mixed models: An open introduction and tutorial in R. Behav Res 53, 2528–2543 (2021). https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-021-01546-0
Westfall, J., Kenny, D. A., & Judd, C. M. (2014). Statistical power and optimal design in experiments in which samples of participants respond to samples of stimuli. Journal of Experimental Psychology: General, 143(5), 2020-2045. https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/xge0000014

And there are also tools you can use to run your own sample size calculations via simulation, such as R packages simr, mixedpower and mlmpower.

What I wanted to say is that the justification of a sample size similar to that of another study that, although it did not analyze the same, analyzed similar things, is sufficient.
By this it means that for example, to calculate the sample size of an LMM, using the GLIMMPSE calculator, it asks for really specific data, such as the average of the groups, the correlation between them, etc..., and all of these data I understand that should be justified in the writing of the article. If we do not have studies that have analyzed this, how can I justify the choice of specific values?

Yeah, it's not easy and there is no "absolute justification". But if those values are the best you can do, then I'd run the analysis with them and explain why you chose them. I find it a good idea - although time-consuming - to run the power calculations several times varying your parameters, e.g. with small and medium correlations between predictors, with small and medium ICC etc. And run all reasonable combinations of parameters.

@Sointu gave you some references on this topic. In addition the second supposition in your first sentence:

linear mixed model requires real data on results

Really isn't correct, nor is it really different from ANOVA (which you contrast tit to). For power analysis of any model there are basically two methods:

Use a canned program which requires you to estimate various quantities.
Simulate the data

It's true that the canned programs for some models (including mixed models) require more estimates than ANOVA. But both require guesses. And the canned programs for many models other than ANOVA/linear regression have limits. E.g. the ones I've seen for Cox regression allow only one or two independent variables.
Also, all canned programs for power analysis require estimates of power, significance, and effect size. For some models, the estimate of effect size is complex.
Finally, I'm not sure what "ethical considerations" there are here.
